# How can i make a multer application so that users can be able to upload multiple images with a single form

Tags: node.js, mongodb, express, multer

How can I make an application like this with multer I'm trying to make it so that users can be able to upload multiple images.

[Reference image](https://i.stack.imgur.com/MJX1O.jpg)

Comment: if you want someone to help you, you need to make a proper question, and also tell what you have tried so far. This type of questions get only disklikes. Try to tell exactly what technologies you are using. If you cant formulate a nice question.. then you need to do more research first. Share your code, share your problem. This question is too broad.. and there are too many answers for this

Answer (score 0):

For references [an example of multer](https://github.com/sumitkumar1207/jwt-auth/blob/master/routes/api/images.js)
You have to change only one thing just put

```
upload.array("images")
```

It will allow you to upload multiple images from single form.